# Can electrical devices be supplied with energy by just EM-waves send through glass fibers?

Tags: electromagnetism, electricity

Electric current supplies energy to our devices by the flow of electric charges through our copper wires. When I'm right, it are the electromagnetic waves of the flowing electron charges which gives energy to these devices. But could it be done too with just EM-waves through glass fibers?

Comment: Are you just thinking of replacing electrical circuits with fiber optics?

Answer (score 1):

Ultimately yes it is the electric field which acts on the electrons which generates electricity and it is the field of moving electrons which moves other electrons that we generally use when we use the electricity.

In practical terms it is possible to generate electricity through energy supplied by an optical fiber. The easiest way is to send light which hits a photo-electric cell and produces a current (ie. shine light through a fiber onto a solar panel)

It is common in telecoms to supply energy to optical amplifiers in a cable by sending light through a separate fiber and using this to generate the power to amplify the signal carrying light. Although in this case the light is used directly to pump a laser which amplifies the incoming light.

Comment: RE powering fiber amplifiers with light, it's important to differentiate that these are optical devices, not electronic devices.

Comment: @ThePhoton - good  point

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible? Yes. Is it efficient? No. Does it offer any advantages over a copper wire? No.

It is perfectly possible to send electrical power wirelessly using EM waves in the radio part of the spectrum. These waves can't be guided by fiber optics, but the analogous waveguide is a coaxial cable. However, using that cable is dumb: that mode of transmission is much less efficient than a standard copper cable, and the only reason you use radio is to untether your device from physical connections.

Swapping the coaxial cable for a fiber, which would only work on the visible or IR sectors, and would therefore be way less efficient, with no advantages to speak of, would be as dumb as it gets. But yes, it can be done.

Comment: There are certain situations where you do not want either RF or copper conductors connecting your device. In those cases, power over optical may be an effective strategy. For example, measurements inside an MRI machine - the presence of strong gradients and RF fields during excitation can set up large common mode currents that can cause burns (blocked with baluns that have their own set of problems). So "no advantages to speak of" depends on the context.

Comment: @Floris Yes, there's always edge cases. I feel the current answer is appropriate to the OP's haphazard and ill-thought-out question.

Comment: avoiding ground loops is often a good thing - and either battery power or power over optical helps in those cases. I don't think it's as "edge" as you say - let's agree to disagree.